# Windows 10: VPN connections displayed as blocked

Tags: windows-10, vpn

I'm creating a VPN Connection in Windows 10. Unfortunately, it doesn't connect and the created connection is displayed as "Blocked" when clicking on the network item in the system tray. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you connected to a network (LAN, Internet, etc.) before trying to connect the VPN?  Is it every VPN connection entry acting like this, or just a specific one?  Have you tried deleting and recreating the VPN connection entry yet?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007, thanks for your comment. Yes, it's connected properly and every VPN connection behaves the same. It apparently never worked on that system. We found in the meantime that the RAS Server doesn't start.